# ASP.NETでDataGridを使おうとしているのですが編集が出来ません

Tags: asp.net

ItemTemplateなどを使わないといけないのでしょうが、初めて使うので良くわかりません｡
なお、表示はできています。

DataGrid を使う理由は、データの作成、修正後保存したいからです。
又、GridViewは変更できないのではと思っているからです｡

**環境:**
VisualStudio 2019
FrameWowk 4.7.2
Windows 10

```xml
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" width="577px" Height="183px" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="日付" DataField="YMD">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="販売店" DataField="TKCD">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundColumn>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Lime" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: そのコードでは分かりません。何でそれで編集ができると思っているのですか？　そのためのコードは実装しているのですか？　それから、なぜ GridView を使わないのですか？　今時 DataGrid を使うことは、保守とか何か特別な理由が無ければあり得ないのですが・・・

Comment: 「WPF DataGrid 編集」等のキーワードで検索して見つかる記事を適用してみては？ [編集 - DataGridクラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2#editing), [【WPF】DataGrid中の任意のセル...](http://pro.art55.jp/?eid=1304203), [...のセルを編集中にする。](http://pro.art55.jp/?eid=1304204), [WPFのDataGridについて](https://akatukisiden.wordpress.com/2017/11/24/wpf_datagrid/), [WPF4.5入門 その23 「DataGridコントロール その1」](https://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/20130218/1358172834), [... その2](https://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/20130224/1361693816), [Single click edit in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3426765/9014308)

Comment: kunif さん> WPF ではなくて、ASP.NET Web Forms アプリの DataGrid だそうです。

Comment: なるほど、「ASP.NET Web Forms DataGrid 編集」だとこちらでしょうか？ [DataGrid クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2), [第12回　Webフォームにおけるデータ連結Part4　DataGridでの編集](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/0212/20/news002.html), [［ASP.NET］DataGridコントロールで編集を可能にするには？](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/fdotnet/dotnettips/081editdg/editdg.html), [ASP:DataGrid　クリックイベント](https://teratail.com/questions/184750)

Answer (score 2):

DataGridは.NET Framework 1.1時（2003年）に設計されたものですが、設計が古く融通が利かないため.NET Framework 2.0時（2005年）に再設計されたものがGridViewです。特別な理由がなければGridViewを検討すべきです。

[DataGrid / Remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)より

> Before you use the DataGrid control, consider using the GridView control instead. The GridView control, which was introduced in the .NET Framework version 2.0, is the successor to the DataGrid control.

Comment: DataGridが古い物だともしりませんでした。
sayuriさんの指摘の通りGridViewを調べてみます。
回答済みの方法が分からないのですが
(回答欄の横にチェックマークが無いのですが)

Comment: > DataGridが古い物だともしりませんでした。　　←質問のコメント欄で最初に言ったのに読んでない？

Comment: @WebSurfer 残念ながらあのコメントでは説明がなく、質問者さんからすれば単なるヒステリーにしか見えないかと。Microsoftが使用を推奨していないことをきちんと説明すべきです。

Comment: @TARO [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) に従いアカウントを統合してください。

Comment: > 質問者さんからすれば単なるヒステリーにしか見えないかと。←相変わらずの無礼なコメントをありがとう。それより回答になってないあなたのレスを何とかした方がよろしいかと。保守でやむを得ずという可能性があることが見えてませんよね。

Comment: みなさま、[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)を守った行動をお願いいたします。親切でフレンドリーな態度を心がけましょう。皮肉な言葉は避け、冗談にも気をつけてください。オンライン上ではそれらのトーンは解釈し辛いものです。